# Visual Studio The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm new to visual studio 2017 and c. Been trying to learn how to use user inputs in my outputs but I keep getting the error, "Unable to start Program The system cannot find the file specified" when I try to run my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float a, b, c;

    printf("enter b");
    scanf("%f,&b");
    printf("enter c");
    scanf("%f,&c");
    a = b * c;
    printf("a=%.2f\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried running a standard, "Hello World" code and that worked just fine.

That would give me the same error. I'm thinking this has to be an error with how I'm setting up the projects in visual studio which has been:

1.New, Project, Visual c++ empty project, ok.

2.Solution explorer, source files, add, new item, c++ file(.cpp) but rename to main.c, add

3. type code

I tried other solutions that people have posted about this question like, build solution, rebuild solution but they didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

It could also be I didn't install visual studio correctly and there's an issue with where its directing its files but I don't know.

edit: I reinstalled visual studio 2017 and still ended up getting the same errors. A simple hello world code works just fine but anything else gives me the error.

Comment: Trying the nuclear option of completely reinstalling visual studio since the other questions on here that people posted didn't help.

Comment: Did you get any errors when you compile? Failing to create the .exe file would be a reason why you cannot run it....

Comment: @Gerhardh when I clicked compile, the only errors I would get would scanf_s () and printf _s () warnings.

Comment: Make sure the New Project is a console project, not a Windows GUI project.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I just do a empty project but I also tried a windows console project (after renaming the file from cpp to c) and that didn't work either

Comment: Are you aware that `scanf("%f,&b");` is as wrong as `scanf("%f,&c");`? Should have been `scanf("%f", &b);` and `scanf("%f", &c);`. `scanf()` is a function with variadic arguments. Needed number of arguments is determined at runtime evaluating first argument. Hence, you may not get compiler errors but the runtime behavior is undefined.

Comment: Do you get errors or warnings? Or are warnings treated as errors? You should show us all errors or warnings. Please use exact copy&paste to edit the messages into your question.